# UINavigationController inside UITabBarController visual issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

For my app I'm using a navigation controller inside my tabbar controller. Everything work fine except one thing. I have a grey bar as the same size of my navigation bar on the top of the screen. I don't succeed to remove it. In the storyboard everything look fine.
Anyone have any idea of what is this grey bar and how remove it?

[image: My storyboard with the navigation controller and the tabbar controller]

The green bar is my navigation bar. I customise it for the first screen.

If i go on another tab item and do `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];`, when i came back the grey bar disappear. 
But if do it directly on the navigation controller the navigation bar disappear and the grey bar stay.

[image: The result on my app]

Comment: Is you tabbar controller inside a navigation controller?

Comment: No the tabbar is the source of the storyboard and i have a navigation controller inside one item of the tab bar

Comment: I find something. If i go on another tab of the tabbar who is not a navigation controller and hide the navigationbar in this one, when i'm returning on the tab with the navigation controller the grey bar is gone and everything is good

Comment: Where is the second segue from your tab bar controller linked ?
I mean there's one going to the navigation controller and another one going to some view controller that doesn't show in your screenshot

Comment: He goes on an other view controller for another tab of the tabbar. It's just a simple view controller with nothing in it for now. When i go in it the grey bar is present too. Except if i do a [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]; on the viewdidappear. If i do this when i came back to the navigation controller the grey bar is gone.
But if i do the navigationbarhidden in the navigation controller the grey bar stay and the navigation bar disappear

Comment: Try to log self.navigationController in viewWillAppear of the tab bar controller

Comment: I got <UINavigationController: 0x7fcbb862f4c0>

Comment: then that's what you are seeing, your tab bar has a navigation controller for some reason, now you have to figure out that reason, or just on the viewWillAppear of the tab bar controller hide the navigation bar

Comment: if you have copied code from somewhere you might have placed a piece of code in your app delegate that embeds you tab bar controller in a navigation controller

Comment: Thank you. Effectively when i called my tabbar from my appdelegate it's was embeb in a navigationviewcontroller. I remove it and it's good.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jad Feitrouni who find my problem. When i called my TabBarController from my appDelegate it was embed in a NavigationController. I removed it and it's good now

Comment: Exactly when you setup In navigation controller you should always check for you navigation bar if  not needed hide it in navigationcontroller.